# Who is Best Suited to Guide the Delivery Process in a Feature Team set-up: QA, Ops Team or Feature PO?

Tags: scrum

A big hurdle when you move your organisation from a component team to a feature team is the delivery process.

Feature teams all code in all components, using branches. Then we live a branch hell. We don't know how and when to deliver and release.

QA and ops team can play a role of regulator, at the end of the chain. As do Feature POs.

How do you organise your deliveries in a feature team organisation?

Comment: This might be better suited to one of the other Stack Exchange sites.  It seems like more of a technical design question than a PM question to me.

Comment: Nyco, welcome to PMSE! I've edited the title to clarify the intent and solicit more feedback from the community. Let me know if I missed the mark.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Tool chains and procedural details are not relevant from the project management perspective. However, the underlying question of how to do continuous delivery within a given framework is certainly relevant.

The short version is that your team must define "continuous" within your organizational context. Once defined, the team must perform all development and integration tasks at a sufficiently granular level to deploy releasable increments at whatever interval you've defined as "continuously."

### Continuous Delivery Requires Continuous Integration

Continuous delivery is basically a rolling-release process, and making a rolling-release project successful usually requires continuous integration. The specifics of how your team *implements* continuous integration (CI) is really a technical issue, and largely outside the scope of project management.

In my personal Scrum implementation experience, the keys to successful continuous integration within the project are:

1. Ensuring that all features have an explicit integration task on the Sprint Backlog.
2. Including integration of the feature into the CI branch in the "definition of done."
3. Sizing features at no more than 4-12 ideal hours to complete. Among other benefits, this avoids long-lived feature branches as a source of integration pain.
4. Migrating completed features to a release branch and/or tagging the release at the end of each sprint. This should also be an explicit story on the Sprint Backlog.

### Continuous Delivery

Continuous delivery means different things in different organizations. I often find that rolling releases based on iterations are sufficiently granular for most projects, but your mileage may vary. Tying deployable increments to a specific Sprint Goal makes it easier to identify the milestones in the project, which is often important even with rolling releases.

In my experience, Scrum projects succeed most with this model when:

1. Deployment and roll-backs from a blessed branch are explicit user stories.
2. Testing and deployment are highly automated, but the processes are fully visible and transparent to the entire cross-functional Scrum Team.
3. The CI and deployment infrastructure provide sufficient project management artifacts to radiate information about the state of the project at all times.
4. Shorter sprint lengths are used in order to minimize the complexity of release-level integration tasks. This has definite trade-offs in project overhead and story sizing, but is an extremely useful technique for continuous delivery.

It's certainly possible to build processes around truly continuous delivery, where every push that passes continuous integration is immediately deployed. However, this requires an extremely high level of automation and feature decomposition, and is usually overkill for most projects.

From a project management perspective, the most important thing is to make sure your entire organization is clear on the accepted definition of "continuous" for your project. In addition, it's a good idea to educate stakeholders (especially the Product Owner) on the trade-offs involved in your process, including costs, cycle time, and team capacity as they relate to the agreed-upon interval.